# Getting a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    if option == 4:
        day5 = int(input('Enter a day:'))
        month5 = int(input('Enter a month:'))
        year5 = int(input('Enter a year:'))
        dateSelected = str(year5+'-'+month+'-'+day5)
        if day == day5 and month == month5 and year == year5:
            print(occurence, ' appointment starting on (', dateSelected, '): ', time, ', ', event)
```

I am getting the error on the line with "dateSelected = str(year5+'-'+month+'-'+day5)".  I have no idea how to fix this.  I have looked for similar question and tried them but it did not help.

Comment: Say you enter `2017` for `year5`.  You're trying to `+` the number `2017` with the character `'-'`.  That doesn't mean anything, so it is throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set month to month5 then tried to get it back by calling month instead of month5.

change

```
dateSelected = str(year5+'-'+month+'-'+day5)
```

to

```
dateSelected = str(year5+'-'+month5+'-'+day5)
```

Comment: No this is not the issue.

Comment: You can realize this has nothing to do because of this line: `if day == day5 and month == month5 and year == year5:`

Answer (score 0):

**At least** `year5` and `day5` are `int`s. The `'-'` are strings. So, you are adding/concatenating a string to an int, which makes no sense.

Python *could* make the types were both `int` or both `string` implicitely. But as both make sense (just regarding the type) both adding and concatenating are defined (not at the same time, obviously). So Python does... nothing, it can't know if you want one or the other.

You may think that taking more information (so it can detect if it's an numeric string, if it were, the string would be implicitly converted to an int, if not the int would be converted) is good, but it's actually a bad idea and makes the operator slower (when used a lot you should be able to notice it).

Replace that line with:

```
dateSelected = str(year5)+'-'+str(month)+'-'+str(day5)
```

Comment: The outer str call is unnecessary.

Comment: True, it **is**, thanks